# Make path as a step-after line in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have designed a graph as shown below:
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is, when Node 3 is dragged from bottom to aside of Node 2, the path should not be a straight line, instead something like a step-after / step-before lines as shown below:
[image]

Is there any way to achieve those type of lines in path that too dynamically ?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: You could use a line generator with step interpolation.